# Recursive JS Function to List Hx HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I have some code:

```
$('section').each(function() {
    var the_id;
    var list_item;
    $(this).find('h2').each(function() {
        the_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('nav > ol').append('<li><a href="#' + the_id + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>');
        $(this).siblings('h3').each(function(i) {
            the_id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (i == 0) {
                $('nav > ol > li:last').append('<ol></ol>');
            }
            $('nav > ol > li:last > ol').append('<li><a href="#' + the_id + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>');
        });
    });
});
```

It generates some HTML like:

```
<li>
   <a href="#example-1">Example 1</a>
   <ol>
      <li>
         <a href="#example-1a">Example 1a</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="#example-1b">Example 1b</a>
     </li>
   </ol>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#another-example">Another Example</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#last-one">Last One</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#just-kidding--another">Just kidding, another</a>
   <ol>
      <li>
         <a href="#this-is-a-sub-header">This is a sub header</a>
      </li>
   </ol>
</li>
```

My issue is, my JS only goes as far as i write it (h2, then looks for h3s, and i'd have to write *another* callback for doing h4's then another for h5's and h6's. How can I write a recursive function that does this?

Comment: If you declare the callback functions separately, and not anonymously, it's easy to write recursive functions in JavaScript. However, I don't see how recursion would help here, since it looks like the logic is different for each header level.

Comment: It's the same for everything after the <h2>'s. It'd always be siblings, but ol > li x whatever <hx> you're on.

Comment: Why recursive? Maybe your question is why doesn't `$("h*")` work and how can I get the same effect, a set of all the h1, h2, h3,...?

Comment: What do you mean by that last bit, `ol > li x`? I get that it's a selector, but I know you don't just mean `ol > li 4` for H4s.

Comment: It needs to nest everything in `<ol><li><ol><li>...` manner. I.e. get all <hx> in one div and then go down through that div for all sub <hx> after grabbing all the sub, go back up to the <h2>s and go into that div grab all the sub hx, etc... its for a ToC: https://skitch.com/oscargodson/rstms/help-viewer

Comment: Looking at the HTML, it seems like you're trying to build a Table Of Contents or something similar?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that this code is meant to modify?

Comment: @Juan : http://oscargodson.com/labs/helpviewer/ it should make sense once you see that

Comment: but again, i dont know the nesting of the <hx> tags or how it'll be written...

Comment: I think you should be using templates to build HTML, not through DOM insertion. I know it doesn't answer the question, but I think it's important since this style is error prone and slower. Look at this link. http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/09/not-using-jquery-javascript-templates-youre-really-missing-out/ I actually use a different library for templating  http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js.html

Comment: @Juan Mendes no worries, I use it JS templates religiously :P. I usually use my own homebrew version, or for larger scale projects I use Mustache and usually have a "partials" dir for getting bigger JS templates. But for example's sake I felt it'd be easier to embed it for StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about another approach to building the list HTML? I really suck at writing/understanding recursive code. Iteration is usually easier for me.

```
function buildToc(container) {
    var html = "", lastLevel = -1;
    container.find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var level = this.tagName.match(/H(\d)/)[1];
        if (lastLevel < level) {
            html += "<ol>";
        }
        if (lastLevel > level)  {
            html += "</ol>";
        }
        html += "<li><a href='"+ this.id + "' >" + $this.text() + "</a></li>";
        lastLevel = level;
    });
    return html;
}
$('nav').append( buildToc( $('article section') ) );
```

I ran that on your page and it duplicated your existing TOC. And you don't need custom code for each level; Quick and dirty.

Comment: Closer, i think, https://skitch.com/oscargodson/rst74/help-viewer -- Except that doesn't look quite right as "Example 1", "Another Example", "Last One", and "Just kidding..." are all siblings, not descendents of Example 1. Recursive functions make my brain explode ;)

Comment: Also see my comment about JS templates!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of staring at this and I think I figured out what you're going for. Each level isn't actually different, you've just explained the minimum in levels to get it all. Like Matt's comment says, you need to declare the callbacks separately. But you also need to pass your current level of list into it, so you can append to the right place. We can try an approach that uses a method for constructing the callbacks, like this:

```
function Generator(e, level) {
    var list = e; // I think you need this for the closure to work, but my js is rusty so I may be wrong.

    return function() {
        var new_list = $('<ol></ol>');
        list.append(new_list); // you might want to make sure there's more than 0 siblings?

        $(this).siblings('h' + level).each(function(i) {
            the_id = $(this).attr('id');
            new_list.append('<li><a href="#' + the_id + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>');
            if (level < 6) { // your max h tag level
                Generator(new_list, level + 1)();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I implemented the thing you're trying to do correctly, but the idea is that you can keep creating sub lists and pass them back into the function recursively. One of your original problems is that you have to make your jQuery selector deeper each time. This approach fixes that. You call it simply:

```
$('section').each(Generator($('nav'), 2)); // maybe not nav, something close to that
```

Obviously your code starts out by using `$(this).find('h2')` instead of `$(this).siblings('h2')`, so some adjustment is needed in that area. But I'm sure that's not a big deal.

I didn't test this, so I probably made at least one mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

<s>A [quick Google](http://www.google.com.ng/search?q=generate%20a%20Table%20Of%20contents%20using%20javascript) search revealed [this script](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/generated-toc/generated_toc.js); it's plain 'ole javascript, but you should be able to adapt it to your needs (or, just borrow the idea and write your own code).</s>

After playing around with this some, I think Juan is right: the iterative approach seems easier. I put together a quick jQuery plugin that uses a similar approach:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.buildTOC = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({
                scan: $(document) // By default, search the entire page for headings
            }, options),
            $toc = $(this),       // This is where we'll place our TOC links

            /*
            * Get the current level from the Heading tag.
            */
            getLevel = function(h) {
                return parseInt(h.substring(1));
            },

            /*
             * Creates a new sublist and returns it.
             * The randomly-generated ID just makes it easier to find the new list.
             */
            pushLevel = function(toc) {
                var id = 'node' + Math.round(Math.random() * 50000 + 1);
                toc.append($('<ol id="' + id + '"></ol>'));
                return $('#' + id, toc);
            },

            /*
             * Returns the last sublist containing an element at the current level;
             * otherwise, returns the parent list (for top-level items).
             */
            popLevel = function(toc, level) {
                var sub = $('.toc-level-' + level + ':last', toc);
                if (sub.length) {
                    return sub.parent();
                } else {
                    return $toc.children('ol');
                }
            },

            /*
             * Appends a link for the current tag to the current list.
             * Also adds a class for the current level (handy for styling), so it's easy
             * to find items at this level.
             */
            appendLink = function(toc, tag, level) {
                toc.append($('<li class="toc-level-' + level + '"><a href="#' + tag.id + '">' + tag.innerHTML + '</a></li>'))
            },

            buildTOC = function(toc) {
                var headings = $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', opts.scan),
                    lastLevel = 0;
                for (var i=0, len=headings.length; i<len; i++) {
                    var currTag = headings[i],
                        currLevel = getLevel(currTag.tagName);
                    if (lastLevel == currLevel) {
                        // Siblings: just add a link for this item
                        appendLink(toc, currTag, currLevel);
                    } else if (lastLevel < currLevel) {
                        // Child: create a new list and append to that
                        toc = pushLevel(toc);
                        appendLink(toc, currTag, currLevel);
                    } else {
                        // Parent: move back out to the appropriate list
                        toc = popLevel(toc, currLevel);
                        appendLink(toc, currTag, currLevel);
                    }
                    lastLevel = currLevel;
                }
            };

        buildTOC($toc);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You'd use it like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('#toc').buildTOC();
})
```

Where `toc` is the ID of the container where the links should go.

Comment: You shouldn't have an answer that just contains a link. You should explain it here briefly.

Comment: And that code looks great and it'll work, but thats a lot of code. This should be a simple recursive function like Tesserex came up with which im still testing.

Comment: @Juan, @Oscar: Quite right fellas...I'm working on it :)
BTW, I thought Tesserex's function was great too.